# React + Axios + Laravel File upload issue when uploading .Nef .CR3 file types

Tags: reactjs, laravel, file-upload, axios

when i upload .jpg , .png files its upload to the storage and show the response and request payload also when i upload .nef or cr3 image files its upload to the storage folder but not showing any response and payload in developer console but status code is 200. I change several content-type of the axios header and tried many times but still same thing. please help me to fix this.

here is axios request

```
 const UploadFiles = async (data, prefix, config) => {
 config['headers'] = {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + Cookies.get("token") ?? "",
 }
 return await axios.post(baseApiURL + prefix, data, config);
};
```

Comment: I've seen something similar to this in Chrome happening when the data exceeds a certain size (I haven't found the specific size limit or any reference to it in browser documentation)... what browser are you using?

Comment: Also, how big are the `.nef` and `.cr3` files you're uploading?

Comment: .nef file current upload one is 12MB. and browser is chrome

Comment: I know that's not a lot in the grand scheme of things, but that's a huge amount of data for the dev tools to try to output... especially if it's in both the request and the response. I've definitely seen Chrome drop output for less

Comment: Could you possibly record a video of the Network tab in dev tools and the output you see when uploading a .jpg file and when uploading a .nef file?